# Can not execute bash script (unexpected element '(' )

Tags: shell, scripting, npm

I have created a script to check if I have installed Node, Npm, Bower and Susy but when I execute it I get an error which I can not solve.

This is the script:

```
    isInstalled(){
  command -v $1 >/dev/null 2>&1 || command -v $2 >/dev/null 2>&1 || { echo >&2 "I require $1 but it's not installed.  Aborting."; return false;}  
}

installNode() {
  if [[ !isInstalled('node', 'nodejs') ]]; then
    echo "Node is not installed. Installing..."
    curl https://www.npmjs.org/install.sh | sh
  fi
}

installBower()
{

   if [[ !isInstalled('npm') ]]; then
     echo "Npm is not installed. Installing..."
     curl -L https://npmjs.org/install.sh | sh
   else
     echo "Npm is installed. Checcking Bower..."
   if [[ !isInstalled('bower') ]]; then
     echo "Bower is not installed. Installing..."
     npm install -g bower
   fi

}

installSusy()
{

  if [[ !isInstalled('npm') ]]; then
     echo "Npm is not installed. Installing..."
     curl -L https://npmjs.org/install.sh | sh
   else
     echo "Npm is installed. Checcking Bower..."
   if [[ !isInstalled('bower') ]]; then
     echo "Susy is not installed. Installing..."
     npm install susy
   fi


}
```

This is the error message:

```
begin.sh: 6: begin.sh: Syntax error: "(" unexpected (expecting "then")
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Functions in `bash` are called just like commands, and not like functions in other languages. Instead of `isInstalled('node', 'nodejs')`, do:

```
isInstalled 'node' 'nodejs'
```

And the `if` condition would look like:

```
if ! isInstalled 'node' 'nodejs';
then
    ...
```